# How do i make sprite color depend on HP variable? (The less hp, the more red sprite should be)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vrd7E.png)

I have a **ShootingEnemy** object that includes **img** object (it has a SpriteRenderer on it). ShootingEnemy can be damaged by shooting it with player's bullets. I want it to become more and more red once its HP level drops. It means that when HP is 5, object has its standart sprite color, when hp is 4 color is a little bit red and when its 1 color is almost completely red
I tried this code(on **ShootingEnemy** object):

```
void Awake() {
bullet = Resources.Load<Bullet>("Bullet");
rb = FindObjectOfType<Hero>().GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
sprite = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
}
void Update() {
    sprite.color = new Color(255, 255f/5*hp, 255f/5*hp);
}
```

and even tried  adding a script onto an **img** object:

```
public class ShootingEnemyChild : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int hp;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;
    private ShootingEnemy parent;
    void Start()
    {
        sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        parent = transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<ShootingEnemy>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        hp = parent.hp;
        sprite.color = new Color(255, (255/5)*hp, (255/5)*hp);
    }
}
```

It seems like object's animation doesnt let it change its color(probably, havent actually checked). when i tried changing color by myself before starting the game it still changed to its natural state, the same thing happened when i started a game and changed the color while it was paused.

Is this idea even realizable? if yes, how do i implement it into my game?

Comment: You've mentioned an animation. What parameters are keyframed?

Comment: Only the sprite itself. It should not do anything with color

Comment: Nevermind, it actually had "Color" as a parameter but i deleted it and after some changes it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html) takes in as arguments, that are floating point values in the range `0` to `1`

```cs
sprite.color = new Color(1f, hp / 5f, hp / 5f);
```

A better way to do it is as follows:

```cs
sprite.color = Color.Lerp(Color.red, Color.green, hp / 5f);
```

Comment: thanks a lot! i cant upvote your answer yet (because i dont have enough reputation) but my feedback should be already recorded

Comment: @boar, now you can do :)